# Solve a renewal equation with Laplace transform

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, laplace-transform

Suppose $u$ satisfies the equation
$$u(x)=\beta\int_0^x u(x-y)dF(y)+v(x)$$ where $0<\beta<1$ and $F(y)$ a distribution function with $F(0)=0$ and $v(x)\geq 0$ continuous for $x\geq 0$. The Laplace Stieltjes transform is $\tilde{f}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sy}dF(s)$. Let $F^{*n}$ be the $n$ times convolution of $F$ with itself. Then the Laplace transform is $\int_0^\infty e^{-sy}F^{*n}(y)=\frac{\tilde{f}(s)}{s}$. Define the compound geometric density function $G(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\beta)\beta^nF^{*n}(y)$. Show that $u$ can be written as $$u(x)=\frac{1}{1-\beta}\int_0^x v(x-y)dG(y)+v(x)$$.

My ideas:
I want to take the Laplace transform of both equations and show that they are the same. The first equation gives me $\tilde{u}(s)=\beta \tilde{u}(s)\tilde{f}(s)+\tilde{v}(s)$. This implies $\tilde{u}(s)=\frac{\tilde{v}(s)}{1-\beta\tilde{f}(s)}$. So I have to show that the second equation gives the same result. How can I go on?

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall that the the Laplace-Stieltjes transform maps the convolution product to the usual product. In consequence, the second equation is transformed into
$$
\tilde{u}(s) = \frac{\tilde{v}(s)\tilde{g}(s)}{1-\beta},
$$
where
$$
\frac{\tilde{g}(s)}{1-\beta} = \sum_{n\ge0} \beta^n \tilde{f}(s)^n = \frac{1}{1-\beta\tilde{f}(s)}
$$
thanks to the geometric series, hence in the end
$$
\tilde{u}(s) = \frac{\tilde{v}(s)}{1-\beta\tilde{f}(s)},
$$
which coincides with your first result. N.B. : your second equation has got one term too many, namely the final $\tilde{v}(s)$, probably due to copying and pasting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is $\tilde{g}(s)=(1-\beta)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \beta^n \tilde{f}(s)$ and not $\tilde{g}(s)=(1-\beta)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \beta^n \frac{\tilde{f}(s)}{s}$?

Comment: @Robert  I used the convolution theorem for the Laplace transform, namely $\mathcal{L}[\phi*\psi] = \mathcal{L}[\phi] \cdot \mathcal{L}[\psi]$. I must admit I don't know where the formula you provided originates from, because $\frac{\tilde{f}(s)}{s}$ corresponds to the Laplace transform of the convolution between $f$ and the Heaviside function.